# How to compare the retrieved text with my expected text?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, protractor, cucumber

I want to compare the retrieved text from the drop down with my expected text.
I am unsure on how to do that as I am new to protractor with cucumber framework.Require some help!

```
  DOM:
  <select id="dropdown1">
  <option value="0" selected="selected">Select training program using 
  Index</option>
  <option value="1">Selenium</option>
  <option value="2">Appium</option>
   <option value="3">UFT/QTP</option>
  <option value="4">Loadrunner</option>
  </select>
```

I have tried the below code but I was getting this error:

AssertionError: expected { Object (browser_, then, ...) } to equal 'Select training program using Index'

```
   Then(/^User clicks the drop down$/, async() => {
   var expected = ['Select training program using Index', 'Selenium', 
   'Appium','UFT/QTP','Loadrunner'];
   var els = element.all(by.id('dropdown1'))
   for (var i = 0; i < expected.length; ++i) {
   expect(els.get(i).getText()).equals(expected[i]); 
   console.log('' +'Steppassed'+ '');
   }
   });
```

I expect the step to be passed as my "expected" and the drop down values are same.

---

The suggestion which you had provided is working but, when I change one of my expected then it should fail.For that I have provided if-else loop but, always it shows that the step is passed.In the below example I have changed 'Appium' to 'A'.

Below is my code.Please help me with the looping:

```
 Then(/^User clicks the drop down$/, async() => {
 var expected = ['Select training program using Index', 'Selenium', 
 'A','UFT/QTP','Loadrunner'];
  var els = element.all(by.id('dropdown1'))
  for (var i = 0; i < expected.length; ++i) {
 if(expect(els.get(i).getText()).to.eventually.equals(expected[i])){
 console.log('' +'Steppassed'+ '');
 }else{
 console.log('' +'Stepfailed'+ '');
  }

   }
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

`getText()` returns a promise, so:

`expect(els.get(i).getText()).to.eventually.equals(expected[i]);`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.I tried using if-else loop to assert whether my expected is not matching with the actual result, then it should fail.But, its not working.

Answer (score 0):

As you are declaring this function async I am assuming you have the SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER set to false in your conf. Based on this you could use awaits to simplify you expect statement.

Additionally, It appears you are trying to use element.all on your dropdown itself which should only ever return one element (the dropdown itself). I believe you want to instead find the dropdown and then get all the options elements.

```
Then(/^User clicks the drop down$/, async () => {
    var expected = ['Select training program using Index', 'Selenium',
        'A', 'UFT/QTP', 'Loadrunner'];
    var dropdown = element(by.id('dropdown1'));
    var dropdownOptions = dropdown.all(by.tagName('option'));

    for (var i = 0; i < expected.length; ++i) {
        let optionText = await dropdownOptions[i].getText();
        //second option to try
        //let optionText = await dropdownOptions[i].getAttribute('value');

        expect(optionText).toEqual(expected[i])
    }
});
```

Note: This approach will only work given that the order of the text in the dropdown is the same as the array you are using.

Comment: No, the one which you suggested is not working.I was getting error like "Cannot read property 'getText' of undefined"

Comment: I'd forgotten to add the dropdown element as the first part of the chain. Could you try again and let me know.